# Criar um marker na posição atual do Maps com Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragment, google-maps-android-api-2

Olá, estou precisando colocar um marker na minha posição atual e mostrar no Google Maps, mas como estou usando Fragment o método setMyLocationEnabled não funciona, já fui atrás na internet em vários sites e não achei a solução, logo decidi perguntar aqui, aqui vai meu código

```
package com.outlier.br.sos_carro.activity.OficinaActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.outlier.br.sos_carro.R;
import com.outlier.br.sos_carro.model.Oficina;

/**
 * Created by daniel on 9/18/16.
 */
public class TabLocalizacaoFragments extends Fragment {

    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    Oficina oficina;



    public void setOficina(Oficina oficina) {
        this.oficina = oficina;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_oficina_localizacao, container, false);

        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mMapView.onResume(); // needed to get the map to display immediately

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {

                googleMap = mMap;
                // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(oficina.getLatitude(), oficina.getLongitude());
                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(oficina.getNome())
                        .snippet(oficina.getDescricao());
                /*
                carro = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title("Minha posiçao");*/
                googleMap.addMarker(options);

                // For zooming automatically to the location of the marker
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(latLng).zoom(15).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `setMyLocationEnabled()` no método `onMapReady()` pois aí tem uma referência ao mapa.

Faça assim:

```
mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        //Apenas para fazer zoom - ver nota
        double lat;
        double long;
        Location location = mMap.getMyLocation();

        if (location != null) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            long = location.getLongitude();
        } 
        LatLng minhaLocalizacao = new LatLng(lat, long);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(minhaLocalizacao, 3));
    }
});
```

**Nota:**

- Terá de lidar com as permissões em tempo de execução se a *targetApi* for 23 ou superior.
- O método [getMyLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation()) é considerado obsoleto, ele é usado aqui porque se pretende que a câmara faça *zoom* naquelas coordenadas. A [documentação](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location#the_my_location_layer) sugere que o *zoom* deve ser feito pelo utilizador, usando o botão no canto superior do mapa.

Comment: Mas, para lidar com as permissões, tenho que pôr esta linha                 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

Mas, o this dá erro, por se estar trabalhando com fragment, não com activity

Comment: Em vez de `this` use `getActivity()`: `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)`

Comment: Por outro lado você pode verificar a permissão na Activity, antes de criar o Fragment.

Comment: Qual a razão para estar a criar um fragment para o mapa? Por que não usa a classe *SupportMapFragment*?

Comment: Olá amigo, este é um trabalho em equipe, para uma disciplina da faculdade e não temos muita experiência com Android, este código acima, mostra a localização de uma oficina no mapa e no final queremos mostrar uma rota entre o ponto atual e esta oficina. Logo, estou adaptando o código para este fim, mas encontrei esta série de problemas... O método getMyLocation, definitivamente não funcionou, não mostrando no mapa a localização.