# Comparar geopontos com geolocalização do usuário

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou usando o **Google Maps API v2** no **Android Studio** e peguei o código-base que a disponibilizada e apenas implementei alguns pontos no mapa, usando latitude e longitude dos pontos (`mMap.addMarker`). Adicionei também a função para localizar o usuário no mapa. Agora preciso que o aplicativo aponte qual desses pontos está mais próximo do usuário.

Teria alguma função na própria API para fazer isso?

Se não, qual seria uma alternativa?

Answer (score 4):

Para calcular a distância, em metros, entre duas coordenadas pode usar a classe [SphericalUtil](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/) da [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/).

Adicione a seguinte dependêcia ao Gradle da aplicação:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

Para calcular a distancia use:

```
double distancia = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(LatLng from, LatLng to);
```

Note que a distância calculada é na superfície da terra e não por estrada.

Comment: excelente resposta..... já agora, é de águeda?

Comment: @LuísAlmeida, sim sou.

Comment: sou de aveiro...tentanto começar desenvolvimento mobile. :)

Comment: @LuísAlmeida boa sorte. :)

Comment: Utilizarei esta, mas antes preciso de uma função que retorne as coordenadas do usuário então... Pois estou usando "mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);", que é uma função disponível direto pela Google Maps API v2, essa função me retorna a localização do usuário como um ponto azul no mapa, mas não retorna as coordenadas...

Comment: Isso é outra pergunta, veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/155011/2541)

Comment: Muito obrigado, essa resposta mencionada usa uma função que está em desuso (deprecated), mas por ela, consegui achar a função usada atualmente pela Google Maps API, aqui está o link para futuros interessados (não sei usar a ferramenta de link kk): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104089/googlemap-getmylocation-cannot-get-current-location