# Como arredondar os valores doubles retornados pela Interface Location

Tags: java, android, google-location-api

Eu possuo um `ArrayList` que guarda objectos de coordenadas de GPS e os seus elementos estão sempre a ser comparados com os valores double retornados pelos métodos `getLatitude()` e `getLongitude()` da *Interface Location*.

#### Problema

Pelos testes que fiz constatei que é muito difícil que o *Smartphone* do usuário capture uma coordenada GPS exactamente igual a algum dos elementos do meu `ArrayList`. Então a solução que encontro para este problema, é arredondar os valores `double` dos objetos do meu `ArrayList` e também arredondar os valores double retornados pelos métodos `getLatitude()` e `getLongitude()` da **Interface Location**, para conseguir detectar com mais sucesso quando o usuário está próximo dos locais que eu pretendo controlar.

Alguém sabe-me indicar qual a melhor forma de arredondar os valores doubles retornados pelos métodos `getLatitude()` e `getLongitude()` ou indicar uma outra solução para este problema?

Em baixo segue o meu `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Coordenada> coordenadasPKs = new ArrayList<>();
    coordenadasPKs.add(new Coordenada(41.148185, -8.584755, 336.1));
    coordenadasPKs.add(new Coordenada(40.82614, -8.59654, 296));
    coordenadasPKs.add(new Coordenada(40.168235, -8.62813666666667, 199));
    coordenadasPKs.add(new Coordenada(39.69546, -8.50684666666667, 135));
    coordenadasPKs.add(new Coordenada(39.6148033333333, -8.49502833333333, 125));
    coordenadasPKs.add(new Coordenada(39.411415, -8.52799166666667, 99));
    coordenadasPKs.add(new Coordenada(39.1335366666667, -8.761665, 59));
```

Comment: Já testou como fica usando `Math.round()` da vida?

Comment: eu tive q fazer isso uma vez com php para gerar um mapa do google mais "preciso" no caso eu nao arredondei , so limitei as casas pois a latitudo é compasta por Graus minuto segundos no caso eu limitei ate os minutos

Comment: calcula todas as distâncias por pitágoras e pega o objeto que gerou a menor delas

Comment: @Gamen, o problema que encontro no método round() da Classe Math, é que ele faz um arredondamento para um valor muito curto e impreciso.

Comment: @J. Guilherme, podia-me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: @VitorMendanha Cara, não sei se é a melhor forma de fazer isso, na verdade acho que é a pior possível, mas já pensou em fazer um cast do valor em uma String, formatar ela para duas casas decimais, sla, quantas você achar melhor, e depois converter pra double novamente?

Comment: @Gamen, eu já tentei utilizar sem sucesso a Classe: DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.000"), para arredondar os valores de Latitude e Longitude do objeto Location e dos objetos do ArrayList. Esperava encontrar outras soluções que fossem mais precisas...

Comment: Segue uma implementação em Java de Haversine, que calcula distância entre 2 coordenadas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23776344/haversine-formula-in-java-producing-incorrect-result - você pode usar isso para avaliar os pontos mais próximos do usuário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arredondar os valores talvez não seja a melhor opção.

O que normalmente se usa nessa situação é a API [GeofencingClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingClient). Ela permite que sejam definidas zonas circulares a partir de uma localização e um raio.

Essa zonas são depois monitorizadas, sendo lançados eventos quando o usuário entra ou saí desse circulo.

Dar uma explicação completa de como usar a API é algo que seria longo demais para uma resposta.
Pode encontrar um tutorial [aqui](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-geofences-on-android--cms-26639) ou consultar [Creating and Monitoring Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) na documentação.

Uma outra opção é criar [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds) e verificar se a localização do usuário esta dentro dele.

Um *LatLngBounds* é um rectângulo definido pelas coordenadas do seus cantos nordeste e sudoeste.

Pode criar um a partir de uma coordenada e distância aos cantos da seguinte forma:

```
//Calcula o ponto à distância 'raio' do 'centro*' na direção 45º(canto superior direito)
LatLng norhtEast = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(centro, raio, 45);

//Calcula o ponto à distância 'raio' do 'centro' na direção 225º(canto inferior esquerdo)
LatLng southWest = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(centro, raio, 225);

LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southWest,norhtEast);
```

Onde

- centro - *LatLng* do centro do rectângulo.
- raio - Distância, em metros, do centro aos cantos superior direito(nordeste) e inferior esquerdo(sudoeste) do *Bounds*

Para verificar se uma *LatLng* está dentro da *LatLngBounds* use:

```
boolean contains = bounds.contains(point);
```

---

**Edit, depois do seu comentário.**

Se não está a usar a api do google maps não tem acesso à classe *LatLngBounds*.

Basicamente o que você pretende é saber se o usuário está perto ou não de um determinado local.
Para determinar isso necessita apenas de definir o que é "estar perto" e uma forma de calcular a distância entre duas coordenadas.

Para calcular a distância deve ser usada trigonometria esférica, normalmente recorre-se a "formula haversine".

Tal como o Bacco disse, existem várias implementações na net, a classe *SphericalUtil* da *lib* [com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) e esta minha [helper classe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21063893/2556111), são exemplos disso.

Adicione um método à sua classe *Coordenada* que indique, segundo o critério(x metros), se as coordenadas passadas como argumento estão perto ao não.

```
private boolean isNear(int criterio, double lat, double long){

    return GeoMath.getDistance(this.lat, this.long, lat, long) <= criterio;
}
```

Comment: ramaral, a minha aplicação não usa os Mapas da Google, dado que ela não necessita dele para a função que está a desempenhar. Pergunto: se eu adicionar no gradle a linha "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'", para que através de um objeto da Interface Location poder criar objetos a Classe LatLng, eu conseguiria criar objetos LatLngBounds ?

Comment: Sim, julgo que isso seria suficiente, no entanto acho um pouco exagerado se a intenção é só usar a classe LatLngBounds. Uma solução menos "pesada" é usar a `com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+` para calcular a distância entre coordenadas. Veja esta [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157036/2541).

Comment: Hoje estou com pouco tempo, amanhã completarei a resposta com uma alternativa ao bounds.

Comment: Se é pra calcular distância em dois pares de cordenadas (o usuário e o ponto de interesse), Haversine é simples e rápido. Tem implementações de monte online. Provavelmente as libs mencionadas na resposta usam coisa do tipo internamente.

Comment: @Bacco Sim é verdade. A *SphericalUtil* que eu refiro usa Haversine. Eu próprio tenho a [minha *"helper class"*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21063893/2556111).

Comment: @ramaral, criei no meu projeto uma Classe GeoMath igual à sua, mas não estou a conseguir importar a Classe GeoPoint? Adicionei no Gradle a linha compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+' e mesmo assim não me aparece a opção para importar a Classe GeoPoint?

Comment: Elimine o método `public static double getDistance(GeoPoint point1, GeoPoint point2)` da minha classe e use o `public static double getDistance(double startLatitude, double startLongitude,
                                     double endLatitude, double endLongitude)`

Comment: Existe outro problema: Não se consegue adicionar no gradle a linha compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+', pois o Android Studio mostra erros no ficheiro: C:\Users\menda\AndroidStudioProjects\Testes_GPS_2\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Se quer usar a minha classe não necessita da `com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+`

Comment: certo, mas a sua Classe "helper classe", possui objetos da Classe GeoPoint que não se conseguem importar?

Comment: Elimine também o `getGeoPointAlongBearing`. Ele não é necessário para o calculo da distância. GeoPoint é uma classe da antiga google maps api.

Comment: o método "isNear", que exemplificou em cima não parece estar bem descriminado ? Se eu criar um assim está correto:  private boolean isNear(int criterio, double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude){

        return GeoMath.getDistance(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude) <= criterio;
    }

Comment: Se o método for criado na sua classe Coordenadas, ele já tem as startLatitude, startLongitude, não precisa de passá-las. Foi o que eu quis dizer com this.lat, this.long

Comment: @ramaral, você está certo naquilo que eu preciso para resolver o meu problema, ou seja, a melhor solução será verificar se o usuário está perto de alguma das coordenadas do ArrayList coordenadasPKs. Vou considerar a sua resposta como aceite. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Conforme sugeri no comentário:

```
int indice = 0;

// lat - latitude do cliente
// lon - longitude do cliente

double menorDistanciaAoQuadrado = Math.Pow(coordenadasPKs[i].getLatitude() - lat, 2) + Math.Pow(coordenadasPKs[i].getLongitude() - lon, 2);

double distanciaAoQuadrado;
for (int i = 1; i < coordenadasPKs.length; i++) {
    distanciaAoQuadrado = Math.Pow(coordenadasPKs[i].getLatitude() - lat, 2) + Math.Pow(coordenadasPKs[i].getLongitude() - lon, 2);
    if (distanciaAoQuadrado < menorDistanciaAoQuadrado) {
        menorDistanciaAoQuadrado = distanciaAoQuadrado;
        indice = i;
    }
}
```

O ponto mais próximo é o de `coordenadasPKs[indice]`. Assim que eu resolveria esse problema.

Comment: Lembrando que pitágoras pra cálculo de geodésica só funciona para distâncias curtas, e longe dos polos, Se fizer um treco desses pra usar na argentina ou na groenlândia, fica absurdamente impreciso. Se usar em lugares extremos (como na transição dos polos ou na "emenda" horizontal da longitude), vai falhar. Melhor mesmo seria usar Haversine (não é tão preciso quanto Vincenty, mas é bem rápido de calcular).

Comment: ótimo ponto, Bacco

Comment: Notar que eu não acho simplesmente errada a solução, só acho que merece uma pequena observação na resposta nesse sentido, para que o usuário, ao escolher a técnica usada, tenha noção das limitações (confesso que eu mesmo já usei isso para uma situação bem específica, num raio limitado de uma cidade da região, antes de implementar Haversine. Mas depois do haversine fiquei um bocado mais tranquilo). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula