# Como criar uma área geofence não circular?

Tags: java, android, maps

Pelo que vi, o geofence cria uma área circular a partir da medida do raio, no caso ele cria uma área circular, mas é possível criar uma área não circular?

Por exemplo um quadrado ou então uma forma abstrata (polígono).

No meu caso queria criar áreas do tamanho dos bairros de uma determinada cidade, se souberem de alguma outra forma de fazer também é válido

Answer (score 1):

Com a forma de um polígono genérico não conheço.

Se a forma de um rectângulo for suficiente use a classe [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds#including(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng))

Para usar, construa um LatLngBounds informando a LatLng do canto inferior esquerdo(southWest) e a LatLng do canto superior direito(norhtEast)

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southWest,norhtEast);
```

Para verificar se uma determinada LatLng se encontra dentro do rectângulo use:

```
boolean contains = bounds.contains(point);
```

Comment: Não precisa colocar o `LatLgn` do centro ou da medida do raio?

Comment: É preciso alguma outra lib, fora a do geofence?

Comment: *"Não precisa colocar o LatLgn do centro ou da medida do raio?"*: se quiser fazer assim veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159166/2541), Julgo que essa classe pertence à api do google maps.