# como consultar a distance matrix com geocoder juntos?

Tags: android, api, google-maps

estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que usa a API do google para exibir no mapa os lugares cadastrados junto com a distancia de cada local da seguinte forma.

```
mMap.addMaker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(nome do local).snippet(distancia do local));
```

Até tudo ok, mas para isso eu sou obrigado a utilizar duas APIs distintas, o distance Matrix (para pegar a distancia) e a Geoconding (para pegar o local, já que so possuo o endereço do local, e não sua LatLng).

Gostaria de saber se e possivel juntar essas duas APIs para conseguir a distancia e o LatLng do local ao mesmo tempo, senão a quantidade de requisições pode acabar extrapolando muito.

Comment: Que tipo de distância quer? É em linha recta?

Comment: podeira ser, mas o ideal seria o tempo a realizar o percurso

Comment: Se for em linha recta pode, caso tenha objectos do tipo [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html), usar `distanceTo(Location dest) ` ou usar a SphericalUtil da Google Maps Android API Utility Library, se tiver objectos do tipo [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng), veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/157036/2541).